# How to set the hostname for a Debian Jessie system?

Tags: debian, hostname, systemd

Debian Jessie comes with `systemd`. The recommendation to set the hostname is using hostnamectl for systemd. However, this command does not work (even to display the current hostname) on the Debian Jessie [image booted on EC2](https://wiki.debian.org/Cloud/AmazonEC2Image/Jessie):

```
sudo hostnamectl
sudo: unable to resolve host ip-172-30-0-17
Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory
```

So I tried to go ahead with Debian's recommendation [here](https://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/ChangeHostname).

```
echo "myhostname" > /etc/hostname
echo "127.0.0.1 myhostname" >> /etc/hosts
/etc/init.d/hostname.sh start
/etc/init.d/networking force-reload
```

However, after logging out and logging in again, the hostname does not change. It does however change after a reboot, but that is not desirable to me.

This method used to work in Debian Wheezy.

Any help with getting this right is appreciated.

Comment: Related: [Debian Hostname refusing to stick](http://serverfault.com/q/175904/130437)

Answer (score 33):

Found the problem. The base AMI on EC2 for Debian Jessie, does not have dbus installed. hostnamectl seems to need dbus. So the fix is to:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y dbus
```

And then:

```
hostname=myname
echo "127.0.0.1      $hostname" >> /etc/hosts
hostnamectl set-hostname "$hostname"
echo "$hostname" > /etc/hostname # uneeded
```

This worked.

Comment: Good catch on the dbus dependency.  FYI: I've been learning how to configure systemd systems and discovered that `hostnamectl set-hostname myhostname` automatically updates the contents of `/etc/hostname` (the static hostname) so there's no need for the first `echo` command.

Comment: Also warning about existing RAIN , may the arrays be adjusted too ?

root@debian:~# rm /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*
root@debian:~# dpkg-reconfigure  openssh-server

And maybe regen initrd too

Comment: @donatello Looks like `timedatectl` have the same dependency towards dbus too... thanks for sharing your solution!

Answer (score 2):

To change the hostanme of your EC2 host, you must follow the steps bellow :

1. Login as root :`$: sudo su -`
2. Install dbus :`$: apt-get update && apt-get install -y dbus`
3. Setup hostname : `hostnamectl  set-hostname <HOSTNAME>`

Make sure to change `<HOSTNAME>` with the hostname you want to set.

Answer (score 0):

We don't actually need to install any package, we just need to edit the file as per you distro from the below list.

```
root@ServerOne:~# ls -l /etc/cloud/templates/
total 32
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1487 Nov 18  2015 chef_client.rb.tmpl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  941 May  3 23:37 hosts.debian.tmpl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  914 Nov 18  2015 hosts.freebsd.tmpl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  912 Nov 18  2015 hosts.redhat.tmpl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  866 Nov 18  2015 hosts.suse.tmpl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  812 Nov 18  2015 resolv.conf.tmpl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1506 Nov 18  2015 sources.list.debian.tmpl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2841 Nov 18  2015 sources.list.ubuntu.tmpl
root@ServerOne:~#
```

Edit the line as below, (Commented one is the original line), replace {{fqdn}} and {{hostname}} as below.

```
#127.0.1.1 {{fqdn}} {{hostname}}
127.0.1.1 ServerOne.opsplus.io ServerOne
```

Alternatively, set  "manage_etc_hosts:" to false as below and you are free to modify /etc/hosts file as it will stop overriding the hosts file.

```
root@ServerOne:~# cat /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/01_debian_cloud.cfg
apt_preserve_sources_list: true
manage_etc_hosts: true
root@ServerOne:~#
```